# Solidity try catch to detect an address type

Tags: try-catch, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am not sure to understand the try / catch in solidity. The following code in intentionally wrong and the error should be caught, right?

```
function GetTest() external view returns (string memory)  {
        
        address _token_addr = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
        console.log("here");
        ERC721 candidateContract = ERC721(_token_addr);
        try candidateContract.supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) {

              console.log("try");
        }
        catch
        {
              console.log("catch");
        }
        return "";
}
```

What is the way to catch an error and check if the address has the expected type (token, address, contract) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The try/catch statement allows you to react on failed external calls
> and contract creation calls

When you call `candidateContract.supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd)` if this function reverts, you will catch the error. For example, if you deploy those `testCatch` and `ERC165` contracts

```
contract testCatch{
    function GetTest() public view returns (string memory)  {
        // this is the address of deployed ERC165 contract down below
        address _token_addr = 0x406AB5033423Dcb6391Ac9eEEad73294FA82Cfbc;
       
        ERC165 candidateContract = ERC165(_token_addr);
        try candidateContract.supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) {

             return "tried";
        }
        catch
        {
              return "catch";
        }  
}

}
interface IERC165 {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool);
}
 
// this contract originally was abstract but I removed it to be able to deploy
contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        // this require will fail
        require(2==3,"wrong calculation");
        return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
    }
}
```

when you call the `GetTest()` function, it will revert because of `require(2==3,"wrong calculation")` line

[image]

However, if you removed the `require` line from `ERC165` contract,

```
contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
    }
}
```

And if you change this `bytes4` "0x80ac58cd" to a wrong `bytes4` "0x80ac5ccc", if you call the function, `catch` will not CATCH it. because `supportsInterface` function will not revert anything. So the code inside `try` block will run